# mousemove on open layers

Tags: jquery, openlayers

Is anybody know how to use this onmousemove event in openlayers?

```
$('#map')[0].onmousemove = (function() {
    var onmousestop = function() {
        $('#tooltip').fadeIn(500);
    }, thread;

    return function() {
        $('#tooltip')
            .css('top', e.pageY + offsetY)
            .css('left', e.pageX + offsetX);
        $('#coor').val(e.pageX + ' - ' + e.pageY);
        $('#tooltip').fadeOut(500);
        clearTimeout(thread);
        thread = setTimeout(onmousestop, 500);
    };
})();
```

I want to add the code above as an event on my open layers. 
I have a working example here.

```
map.events.register('mouseout', map, function (e) {
    $('#tooltip').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A map object in OL support many type of events.

Here is the list (http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html)

```
preaddlayer ==> triggered before a layer has been added.  
addlayer ==> triggered after a layer has been added. 
preremovelayer ==> triggered before a layer has been removed.  
removelayer ==> triggered after a layer has been removed. 
changelayer ==> triggered after a layer name change, order change, opacity change, params change, visibility change (due to ==> resolution thresholds) or attribution change (due to extent change).  
movestart ==> triggered after the start of a drag, pan, or zoom
move ==> triggered after each drag, pan, or zoom
moveend ==> triggered after a drag, pan, or zoom completes
zoomend ==> triggered after a zoom completes
mouseover ==> triggered after mouseover the map
mouseout ==> triggered after mouseout the map
mousemove ==> triggered after mousemove the map
changebaselayer ==> triggered after the base layer changes
```

Why aren't you using these events with something like that :

```
map.events.register('move', map, function (e) {
    $('#tooltip')
            .css('top', e.pageY + offsetY)
            .css('left', e.pageX + offsetX);
    $('#coor').val(e.pageX + ' - ' + e.pageY);
});

map.events.register('movestart', map, function (e) {
    $('#tooltip').fadeIn(500);
});

map.events.register('moveend', map, function (e) {
    $('#tooltip').fadeOut(500);
});
```

Comment: I tried your example but they didn't work. Actually the thread on my code works like when the mouse is moving then the tooltip will not show, when the mouse stop moving then the tooltip will appear.

Comment: Hi, your example is just the same as mine. On my question above I am using thread, is it possible for open layer to have this function?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use that because with your `setTimeOut` the `fadeIn` will be triggered on each mousemove event after 500 milliseconds. Maybe you can try to check if the element is hidden and then call the `setTimeOut` in the `movestart` event